# Core Reporting API - Advanced filter

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to run the same query that I use on the Google Analytics web application with The [google analytics reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).

I want an advanced filter to check `pageviews` for urls with a specific folder (*/folder/*) and must `ignore pageviews` that have a specific source (*ignore*).

I have this:

```
{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "viewId": "xxxx",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2020-02-01", "endDate": "2020-02-21"}],
      "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:pageviews"}],
      "dimensionFilterClauses": [{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath","operator": "BEGINS_WITH","expressions": ["/folder/"]}]},{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:source","operator": "!=","expressions": ["ignore"]}]}]
    }
  ]
}
```

The **/folder/** part is ok. But I don't know how to exclude the **ignore**.

Could you help me?

Comment: The dimensionfilterclause doesnt have an exclude option what does your filter on the website look like exactly? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilterclause

Answer (score 0):

I've set up filters before similar to how you're wanting to use them here.

I use essentially a combination of the following:

```
Dimension Filters:
  ==   Exact match
  !=   Does not match
  =@   Contains substring
  !@   Does not contain substring
  =~   Contains a match for the regular expression
  !~   Does not match regular expression


Combining Filters with “And” and “Or” Operators:
  And   “ ; ”
  Or    “ , “
```

I have a repo with example code of report requests that you can repurpose if that assists you here: https://github.com/jessfeliciano/aggregateGoogleAnalyticsReporting/blob/master/objectQueryWithFilter.js

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any follow up questions.